# Password verification not working with a particular sequence

Tags: java

i have written this method

```
public boolean passwordCheck(String password)
{
    boolean isValid = false;
    int numCount = 0;

if(password.length() < 8){
    return false;
}

for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
    if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
    return isValid;
}
```

and when I do passwordCheck("a * b * e * d * c") (imagine no spaces in between the asterisks) it should return false because i have the

```
if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
```

so since there are things in the password that are not valid characters i would expect it would return false but that is not the case.

Comment: provide the return statement after checking all character in password

Comment: why didn't used regex to validation it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "return" when a character is "unacceptable" (`return false`) This is OK - because "one bad apple will spoil the bunch".

And also: "One invalid character means the whole password is invalid..." But if you return `true` just because one character is valid / true. That is the mistake in your method. –

```
public boolean passwordCheck(String password)
{
    if(password.length() < 8) return false;

    for(int i=0; i < password.length(); i++)
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you use "return" when a character is "unacceptable" (return false)  This is OK - because "one bad apple will spoil the bunch" ... And also ... "One invalid character means the whole password is invalid...."  **BUT IF** you return true ... Just because **ONE CHARACTER** is **valid / true**... Well... That is the mistake in your method.

Answer (score 1):

You return true after your first character is a letter or digit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to return `true` until after you've checked *every* character.  But currently, you're returning `true` as soon as you've checked the first one.

One possible solution is to get rid of the `else` clause, and move the `return true;` down outside the loop, like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
    if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i)))
    {
       return false;
    }
}
return true;
```